# How can I pick a random string from an array and display it in a text box?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, user-interface, random

What I am trying to do is to pick a string from my array that I have set up at random and then display it int a text box named txtResults. I am not sure how to achieve this as I am fairly new to C# as well as creating GUIs. Any advice or help is greatly appreciated.

```
private void btnMexican_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] mexicanRestaurants =
    {
        "Jose Locos/n853 N Glenstone Ave, Springfield, MO 65802/n(417) 831-1300",
        "Tortilleria Perches\nElfindale Center, 1601 W Sunshine St, Springfield, MO 65807\n(417) 864-8195",
        "Purple Burrito\n5360 S Campbell Ave Springfield, MO 65810\n(417) 883-5305",
        "Amigos Mexican Restaurant\n2118 S Campbell Ave, Springfield, MO 65807\n(417) 887-1401",
        "Cantina Laredo\nAddress: 4109 S National Ave, Springfield, MO 65807\n(417) 881-7200"
    };

    Random rand = new Random();

    // Now what??
}
```

Comment: `var randomString = mexicanRestaurants[rand.Next(mexicanRestaurants.Length)]`, simple enough to figure out from there

Answer (score 2):

To get the string:

```
String result = mexicanRestaurants[rand.Next(mexicanRestaurants.Length)];
```

Then to set it to the textbox:

```
txtResults.text = result;
```

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are the docs on Random. Like jdphenix said in comments, `rand.Next(mexicanRestaurants.Length)` should give you an appropriate index.